# Adding RichText to custom multifield widget is not working properly in cq5

Tags: extjs, aem

When a CQ.form.RichText is added to a custom multifield widget in cq5 , the content of rich text component is disappearing when the dialog is opened again for editing or adding new entry of custom widget.
Clicking OK makes the content disapper on cq component's .html page.

Looking for inputs and if any one has come across such issue, could you please direct me to the solution approach.

**EDIT :**

here is the code sample from custom.js (just posting RichText portion, there is a DateTime and TextField along with richtext in the custom widget)

```
this.news= new CQ.form.RichText({
        cls: "customwidget-4",
        fieldLabel: "News",
        allowBlank: false,
        listeners: {
            change: {
                scope: this,
                fn: this.updateHidden
            },
            destroy: {
                scope: this,
                fn: this.descDestroy
            }
        }
    });
    this.add(this.news);
```

and here is the descDestroy snippet:

```
descDestroy: function() {
    this.news.el.dom = {};
}
```

then registering custom widget as xtype:

```
CQ.Ext.reg("CustomNews", CQ.form.CustomNews);
```

Using the above "CustomNews" in dialog.json:

```
{
"title": "Custom News Widget",
"jcr:primaryType": "cq:Dialog",
"xtype": "dialog",
"items": {
    "jcr:primaryType": "cq:WidgetCollection",
    "tab1": {
        "jcr:primaryType": "cq:Widget",
        "title": "News Component",
        "xtype": "panel",
        "items": {
            "jcr:primaryType": "cq:WidgetCollection",
            "news": {
                "jcr:primaryType": "cq:Widget",
                "fieldDescription": "Press + to add more links",
                "fieldLabel": "News",
                "hideLabel": false,
                "name": "./news",
                "width": 1000,
                "xtype": "multifield",
                "fieldConfig": {
                    "jcr:primaryType": "cq:Widget",
                    "xtype": "CustomNews"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would try debugging especially if you are using a custom multifield widget. This can be quite tricky and multifields are hard to handle.

Comment: Please post the code snippet related to the issue so that others can debug / suggest a fix. Also add the version of CQ5 that you are working in.

Comment: When you edit the data first time does it goes to crx ? In order for multifield to store the data in the crx you may need changes to the getValue and setValue, of xtype multifield. In short the data been stored using multifield is always a string array representation, hence multifield of textfield stores the data of each textfield in a string array, this differs for rich text. Please check if the data get posted in crx, later when component gets edited a get request happens and this is where in you will need a debug.

Comment: @yashahuja, thanks for the input, actually I solved this issue back in July.I'll update this question soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just wanted to update the question with my answer, just to keep it as a reference for others if they come across the similar issue:

Actually this problem was faced when the richtext is the last component in your custom xtype and I don't know why , but the change listener assigned to the richtext was not firing when ever the text changed in that component.
So that caused the issue of value not getting updated on the CQ5 page when the OK button on the dialog was clicked.
To overcome this, I just used `beforesubmit` listener in the dialog to do `component.setValue(component.getValue())` to again update the values of the components in the custom xtype. 
Here is my dialog:

```
{
"title": "Custom News Widget",
"jcr:primaryType": "cq:Dialog",
"xtype": "dialog",
"items": {
    "jcr:primaryType": "cq:WidgetCollection",
    "tab1": {
        "jcr:primaryType": "cq:Widget",
        "title": "News Component",
        "xtype": "panel",
        "items": {
            "jcr:primaryType": "cq:WidgetCollection",
            "news": {
                "jcr:primaryType": "cq:Widget",
                "fieldDescription": "Press + to add more links",
                "fieldLabel": "News",
                "hideLabel": false,
                "name": "./news",
                "width": 1000,
                "xtype": "multifield",
                "fieldConfig": {
                    "jcr:primaryType": "cq:Widget",
                    "xtype": "CustomNews"
                }
            }
        }
    }
},
 "listeners": {
        "jcr:primaryType": "nt:unstructured",
        "beforesubmit": "function(){var comp= this.findByType(\"CustomNews\"); for(var i=0;i<comp.length;i++){ comp[i].setValue(comp[i].getValue());}}"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To create richtext in custom multifield of extjs, i have done all the steps mentioned above but my richtext node in dialog in my AEM page gets disabled.

I have enclosed my extjs code, please let me know whether i am making any mistake.

/**
* @class Ejst.CustomPathFieldWidget
* @extends CQ.form.CompositeField
* This is a custom path field with link text and target
* @param {Object} config the config object
*/
/**
* @class Ejst.CustomWidget
* @extends CQ.form.CompositeField
* This is a custom widget based on {@link CQ.form.CompositeField}.
* @constructor
* Creates a new CustomWidget.
* @param {Object} config The config object

*/

CustomPathFieldWidget = CQ.Ext.extend(CQ.form.CompositeField, {

```
/**
* @private
* @type CQ.Ext.form.TextField
*/
hiddenField: null,

/**
* @private
* @type CQ.Ext.form.TextField
*/
linkText: null,

/**
* @private
* @type CQ.Ext.form.TextField
*/
linkURL: null,

/**
* @private
* @type CQ.Ext.form.CheckBox
*/
openInNewWindow: null,

/**
* @private
* @type CQ.Ext.form.FormPanel
*/
formPanel: null,

constructor: function (config) {
    config = config || {};
    var defaults = {
        "border": true,
        "labelWidth": 125,
        "layout": "form"
    };
    config = CQ.Util.applyDefaults(config, defaults);
    CustomPathFieldWidget.superclass.constructor.call(this, config);
},

//overriding CQ.Ext.Component#initComponent
initComponent: function () {
    CustomPathFieldWidget.superclass.initComponent.call(this);

    this.hiddenField = new CQ.Ext.form.Hidden({
        name: this.name
    });
    this.add(this.hiddenField);

    this.linkText = new CQ.form.RichText({
    cls: "customwidget-1",
    fieldLabel: "Link Text11: ",
    allowBlank: true,
    enableSourceEdit: true,
    hidden:true,
    externalStyleSheets:"[/etc/designs/web-2013/clientlibs_all.css]",
    emptyText: "Enter the text to show to the customer on answer selection",
    width: 500,
    rtePlugins :{
        spellcheck:{features:"*"},
        image:{features:"*"},
        edit:{features:"*"},
        justify:{features:"*"},
        misctools:{features:"*"},
        table:{features:"*"},
        undo:{features:"*"}
    },
    listeners : {
        change :{
            scope : this,
            fn : this.updateHidden
        },
        destroy: {
            scope:this,
            fn:this.destroyRichText
        }
    }
    });
    this.add(this.linkText);

    this.linkURL = new CQ.form.PathField({
        cls: "customwidget-2",
        fieldLabel: "Link Path: ",
        width: 400,
        listeners: {
            change: {
                scope: this,
                fn: this.updateHidden
            },
            dialogclose: {
                scope: this,
                fn: this.updateHidden
            }
        }
    });
    this.add(this.linkURL);
},

processInit: function (path, record) {
    this.linkText.processInit(path, record);
    this.linkURL.processInit(path, record);
},

setValue: function (value) {
    var link = JSON.parse(value);
    this.linkText.setValue(link.text);
    this.linkURL.setValue(link.url);
    this.hiddenField.setValue(value);
},

getValue: function () {
    return this.getRawValue();
},

getRawValue: function () {
    var link = {
        "text": this.linkText.getValue(),
        "url": this.linkURL.getValue(),
    };
    return JSON.stringify(link);
},

updateHidden: function () {
    this.hiddenField.setValue(this.getValue());
},

destroyRichText : function() {
     this.el.dom={};
```

}

});
CQ.Ext.reg('linkscustom',CustomPathFieldWidget);